# How to implement 'Lead Score' in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We have to update 'Lead Score'on basis of subscriber activities (Open/Click) for every email deployment. Emails will be deploying from 'Journey Builder'. Unfortunately we do not find option in 'Salesforce Marketing Cloud'. So let me know if there are any possibilities.

Example: if subscriber opened first email then Lead Score ="100"
if subscriber clicked on particular link="100"
if subscriber clicked on particular link twice or thrice ="200" or "300"

Answer (score 2):

Warning: Marketing Cloud was not built for this. Lead scoring is primarily a B2B marketing Function and Pardot is more suited to this use case.

But if you must use marketing cloud,

1. Create two Data Extensions. One to store the behavioural attributes(click , opens) and another to store the the demographics(address, location, job title)
2. Assign scores that determine your business value the businesses value to them. This will involve consulting with marketing to sales to determine which behaviours / demographics consititute "a good lead"
3. Write queries to calculate the scores based on the value in the Data Extensions from Step 1. For example, If i a campaign, there are two clicks, the queries would multiply the column in 1 * 2 and add it to the lead's score (This can be stored in a separate table or anywhere that is easy to retrieve

Automate this process according to your desired cadence.

You might also find that Predictive Intelligence gives you a better proxy to lead scoring.